# TL431 output voltage

Tags: integrated-circuit, tl431

Recently, I use the Tl431 to be a regulator, and I want to change the output of TL431.

I read the [TI datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl431.pdf?ts=1617762640525&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) if I want to change the output I need to change the divider resistor, and I also use PSIM to simulate it, it can works.
but I don't know how to analyze it, I want to know why the output voltage can be written as Vref*(1+R1/R2)+Iref*R1

can someone give me some advice?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [TL431](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl431.pdf?ts=1617762640525&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) is a high gain device with an internal voltage reference. When the external input is slightly **above** the reference voltage, cathode and anode are effectively connected together with a low resistance. When the external input is slightly **below** the reference input, cathode and anode are, in effect open circuit.

So, if you use two resistors to form a potential divider from cathode to anode and connect the middle node to the reference input, due to negative feedback and internal high-gain, the reference input acquires the same voltage as the internal reference voltage (2.495 volts typically).

So, we have a potential divider where the TL431 adjusts/shunts \$V_{KA}\$ to make \$V_{REF}\$ = 2.495 volts hence, the resistive potential divider equation is: -

$$\dfrac{V_{REF}}{V_{KA}} = \dfrac{R2}{R1+R2}$$
$$$$

$$V_{KA}= V_{REF}\cdot \dfrac{R1 + R2}{R2} = V_{REF}\cdot\left(1 + \dfrac{R1}{R2}\right)$$

$$$$

That's the basic formula but if you want to factor in the slight error caused by the reference input bias current (\$I_{REF}\$) then that formula becomes as stated in your question and the data sheet.

Proof that imagines R2 to be in parallel with \$R_{REF}\$ where \$R_{REF} = V_{REF}/I_{REF}\$: -

[image]

Comment: Hi Andy 

Thank you for your explanation 

but I don't understand why the Bias current (Iref) needs to times R1, not R2. 

do you know why?

Comment: @Jitter456 I've added the math that should make this clear.

Comment: Hi Andy
your math proof makes me more clear right now.
but why can you said there has a resistor in the TL431?

Comment: @Jitter456 if the input takes current and there's a voltage at that input, then that input can be regarded as being equivalent to a resistor Rref in parallel with R2.